# TypeError: 'RegistrationForm' object is not callable

Tags: python

Morning Fellas!

I'm facing some troubles with a Flask form. Here is the code (python2.7):

**views.py**

```
    # third-parties imports
    from flask import flash, redirect, render_template, url_for
    from flask_login import login_required, login_user, logout_user

    # local imports
    from . import auth
    from forms import LoginForm, RegistrationForm
    from .. import db
    from ..models import Empregado

    @auth.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def register():
        form = RegistrationForm()
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            empr = Empregado(email=form.email.data,
                   username=form.username.data,
                   first_name=form.first_name.data,
                   last_name=form.last_name.data,
                   password=form.password.data)
            db.session.add(empr)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Registration complete! Go ahead and Login!')

            # done registration. Heads for login
            return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))

        # When FLASK_DEBUG = 1, it yells a TypeError on the following line
        return render_template('auth/register.html', form=form('utf8'), title='Register')
```

**forms.py**

Altough RegistrationForm is not callable, LoginForm is rendered on auth/login.html, so the snippet of code above only focus on the error on auth/register.html

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# app/auth/forms.py

from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import PasswordField, StringField, SubmitField, ValidationError
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Email, EqualTo
from ..models import Empregado

class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):

    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    username = StringField('User', validators=[DataRequired()])
    first_name = StringField('First name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    last_name = StringField('Last name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('retype')])
    retype = PasswordField('Retype Password')
    submit = SubmitField('submit')

def validate_email(self, field):
    if Empregado.query.filter_by(email=field.data).first():
        raise ValidationError('Email already used')

def validate_username(self, field):
    if Empregado.query.filter_by(username=field.data).first():
        raise ValidationError('User already exists')

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):

    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Login')
```

**Traceback**

```
File "~/Sources/py2/business_masters/app/auth/views.py", line 40, in register

return render_template('auth/register.html', form=form('utf8'), title='Register')

TypeError: 'RegistrationForm' object is not callable
```

I have double-checked for typos and directories, but everything seems fine... I'm stuck on this (my first website, so please, don't go hard on this poor dev...). I appreciate your comprehension and time fellas!

Comment: Please add your `RegistrationForm` part.

Comment: Why are you doing `form=form('utf8')` and not just `form=form`?

Comment: Because it yells at me UnicodeDecode error if I don't... I believe python2.7 default encoding is 'ascii'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`form=form('utf8')` which means you're passing a **class** object to `form` not an instance.

Try to use `return render_template('register.html', form=form)`.

Here is an example,check out your code and compare with your `RegistrationForm`:

```
from wtforms import Form, StringField, validators

class RegistrationForm(Form):
    username = StringField('Username', [validators.Length(min=4, max=25)])
    email = StringField('Email Address', [validators.Length(min=6, max=35)])

@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        user = User(form.username.data, form.email.data,
                    form.password.data)
        db_session.add(user)
        flash('Thanks for registering')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```

register.html:

```
<form class="form form-horizontal" method="post" role="form">
    {{ form1.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ wtf.form_errors(form1, hiddens="only") }}
    {{ wtf.form_field(form1.email,form_type="horizontal") }}
    {{ wtf.form_field(form1.username,form_type="horizontal") }}
    {{ wtf.form_field(form1.first_name,form_type="horizontal") }}
    {{ wtf.form_field(form1.last_name,form_type="horizontal") }}

  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
     <button name="action_save1" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

See more details from [Form Validation with WTForms](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/wtforms/).

Comment: Thanks! I'll compare and share the results!

Comment: @G.BossNoobware you can use `import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')` to avoid UnicodeDecode error and change `form=form('utf8')` to `form=form`

Comment: @G.BossNoobware you can just use `form = RegistrationForm()`

Comment: the error still persists., even after importing everything, Traceback:'RegistrationForm' is not callable - To be honest, I'm stuck with this error for 3 long days...

Comment: @G.BossNoobware `return render_template('auth/register.html', form=form, title='Register')` it works for me.`form=form('utf-8')` means you're passing a **class** object,`form=form` passes an instance.

Comment: Thanks! That's absolutely right! form=form passes an instance, and that's how supposed to be! After setting sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8') on the views.py, it worked!